# Does Ethereum have a payment URI like Bitcoin?

Tags: mist, bitcoin

Does Ethereum offer a payment URI [like Bitcoin does](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki)?
I'd like a user to be able to click a link and have a wallet (Mist) open with a transaction to that address.

### Examples

Just the address:

```
bitcoin:175tWpb8K1S7NmH4Zx6rewF9WQrcZv245W
```

Address with name:

```
bitcoin:175tWpb8K1S7NmH4Zx6rewF9WQrcZv245W?label=Luke-Jr
```

Request 20.30 BTC to "Luke-Jr":

```
bitcoin:175tWpb8K1S7NmH4Zx6rewF9WQrcZv245W?amount=20.3&label=Luke-Jr
```

[more here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki#examples)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of proposals, but I don't think either of them are widely supported yet:

[EIP 681: URL Format for Transaction Requests](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-681.md)
This provides for a standard URI scheme including a function name and parameters.
(This supercedes https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/67

IBAN URLs for payments:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/ICAP:-Inter-exchange-Client-Address-Protocol

Answer (score 2):

It is not registered in the URI schemes registry http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xml , unlike bitcoin, but it could. eth: ? ethereum: ?